# Change unit of axis

Tags: plotting, scaling

[image]

I want to plot a trigonometry function (for example : $\lfloor 2\cos x\rfloor$) using Mathematica. And I want to scaling x axis using multiples of $\pi$ . For example $\frac{\pi}{2}$ , $\pi$ , $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ and $2\pi$. But in the graph  doesn't show exact point of roots.

Please Help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936579/labeling-a-plot-in-increments-of-pi

Comment: @Alan Thank you , But it doesn't show exact values of roots in the graph versus $\pi$ multiples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sol = Sort@
  DeleteDuplicates@
   Cases[Table[
     Reduce[Floor[2 Cos[x]] == i && 0 < x < 2 Pi, x], {i, -2, 2}], 
   _Times, Infinity]
```

[image]

```
ticks = Transpose@{sol, sol};

Plot[Floor[2 Cos[x]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> {Range[-2, 2]}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[.02]],
  Ticks -> {ticks, Automatic}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic ! Thank You.

Comment: Can you provide a good source for learning Mathematica ?

Comment: @S.H.W Practice and this site :)

Comment: In your picture , some of points must be empty. How I can determine this points ?

Comment: What is an empty point?